# How to restore file permissions to default in ubuntu

Tags: default, file-permissions, ubuntu-20.04

While working in eclipse I realised that my pom.xml file had read-only permissions. In order to change that I ran

```
sudo chmod +rwx '/home/babi-b/eclipse-workspace/TodoApp'
```

To change permissions in the entire directory (TodoApp) where the file is found. However, permissions of the entire system has been changed to read-only.

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/babi-b/eclipse-workspace/TodoApp': Read-only file system
```

I just restarted my machine and now it stuck on this console

[image: screen image]

Please, how do I reset the system to default?

I am working on ubuntu 20.04

This is what my screen now looks like

[image: screen image]

Is there a way for me to recover without losing my data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work in your case, but it did for me when I got the "BusyBox" screen.

At the `(initramfs)` prompt:

1. Type `exit`
2. Type `fsck /dev/sda1 -y`
3. This will scan and fix the file system. Once it's done, you can type `reboot`.

By the way, if `/dev/sda1` doesn't work, you can try `/dev/sda2`, etc.

source: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=241789

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just run live Linux from eg. a USB stick, mount your broken volume, and set permissions as you wish.